# Performing analysis with sDNA toolbox using ArcGIS Notebook

Tags: arcgis-pro, sdna, arcgis-notebook

I am trying to perform 'arcpy.Spatial Design Network Analysis.sDNAPrepare' command using ArcGIS Notebook on ArcGIS Pro (ver. 2.7.1). However, I have failed to run the command.

What is the problem and What should I do?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"D:/sDNA/sDNA.pyt")
arcpy.Spatial Design Network Analysis.sDNAPrepare(r"C:/Users/14009/Desktop/shanghai_sdna/shanghai_sdna_test/shanghai_network_center/shanghai_network_center.shp",  r"C:/Users/14009/Desktop/shanghai_sdna/shanghai_sdna_test/sdna_prepare_test/prepare_test.shp", None, None, "REPAIR", True, False, True, True, True, None, '', '', '', '', '', '')
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ast.py, in parse:
Line 50:    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include Python command and error message as text.

Comment: You have space characters between the text "spatial design network analysis", that is invalid syntax as the error message indicates.

Comment: @user2856 you’re right - I mistook it for a picture and incorrectly voted to close it as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sDNA authors have used an [invalid alias](https://github.com/fiftysevendegreesofrad/sdna_open/issues/14) for the ArcGIS Toolbox.

You can set your own alias (`module_name` parameter) in [`arcpy.ImportToolbox`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/importtoolbox.htm). E.g

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"D:/sDNA/sDNA.pyt", "sDNA") 
arcpy.sDNA.sDNAPrepare(r"C:/Users/etc...")
```